# AWS Lambda: "ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned" when deployed via Serverless Framework

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a Lambda function in python3.6 that uses the following packages:

```
opencv-python
imutils
numpy
joblib
mahotas
scikit-image
scikit-learn==0.22.1
sklearn
pymongo==3.10.1
```

I am using the Serverless Framework to minimize the deployment sizes and to deploy to lambda. I've used the `serverless-python-requirements` plugin to manage packages. This is what my template.yml file looks like:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    zip: true
    slim: true
    noDeploy:
      - boto3
      - botocore
      - docutils
      - jmespath
      - pip
      - python-dateutil
      - s3transfer
      - setuptools
      - six
      - tensorboard
package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - model/**
    - .vscode/**
```

I need to use `slim` & `zip` option because otherwise the deployment package will be too large (~350mb).

For some reason, if I don't include `pymongo` in `requirements.txt`, the function runs fine. The output of `sls deploy` when `pymongo` is not included is:

```
Serverless: Adding Python requirements helper...
Serverless: Generated requirements from /home/amman/Desktop/serverless-hello-world/requirements.txt in /home/amman/Desktop/serverless-hello-world/.serverless/requirements.txt...
Serverless: Using static cache of requirements found at /home/amman/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/3967fa669ece2345132bfe2a31be4287e2d61deedfb8b6006997a2192cea5753_slspyc ...
Serverless: Zipping required Python packages...
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Removing Python requirements helper...
Serverless: Injecting required Python packages to package...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service hello-world.zip file to S3 (128.52 MB)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
.........
Serverless: Stack update finished...
```

So the total .zip size is ~128 MB, and the function runs fine. But, if I include `pymongo`,the output of `sls deploy` is:

```
Serverless: Adding Python requirements helper...
Serverless: Generated requirements from /home/amman/Desktop/serverless-hello-world/requirements.txt in /home/amman/Desktop/serverless-hello-world/.serverless/requirements.txt...
Serverless: Installing requirements from /home/amman/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/279b0240a975ac6ad3c96e3b0ed81eec7981a8e66e0216037484878bfcaf4479_slspyc/requirements.txt ...
Serverless: Using download cache directory /home/amman/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/downloadCacheslspyc
Serverless: Running ...
Serverless: Zipping required Python packages...
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Removing Python requirements helper...
Serverless: Injecting required Python packages to package...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service hello-world.zip file to S3 (109.37 MB)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
.........
Serverless: Stack update finished...
```

Now the size is decreased to ~109 MB. Shouldn't the size increase because I've added a new dependency? When I run the lambda function, I get an error:

> Unable to import module 'handler': /tmp/sls-py-req/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned

I think this might be a serverless framework issue. What could I do to fix this? I have tried installing different versions of `pymongo` but no luck.

I am using the following Serverless Framework version:

```
> serverless --version
Framework Core: 1.73.1
Plugin: 3.6.13
SDK: 2.3.1
Components: 2.31.2
```

Edit: Are there any alternative to pymongo? I've seen some but they use pymongo as the underlying dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't fix this with serverless. So I decided to `sls deploy` without `pymongo` and once serverless generated the `.requirements.zip` file, I copied that file elsewhere and once again ran `sls deploy` but this time with only `pymongo` (and `pymongo[srv]`) in `requirements.txt`. That generated `.requirements.zip` containing pymongo and its dependencies. I merged files from this `.requirments.zip` and the one `requirements.zip` generated from the first `sls deploy`. This way I got all other dependencies (opencv2, numpy, joblib etc) and pymongo in one `.requirements.zip` file.

After that I zipped the source code plus the merged `.requirements.zip` file and **manually** uploaded the zip to s3. It came down to 128MB zipped. Pointed my lambda function to use this deployment package from S3 and it worked. I got pymongo along with opencv2 and other dependencies.

But, a drawback is that you have to upload to S3 and update the function yourself. Until this is problem is fixed, I am going to have to use this "hack".

Comment: it's probably related to `serverless-python-requirements` running `strip` on the `.so` files:
https://github.com/serverless/serverless-python-requirements/blob/891a53847e0053ce69f959e27830cd4859f932a0/lib/slim.js#L25

Answer (score 0):

Use layers.
Pack functions individually.

```
  lambda:
handler: lambda/handler.lambda_handler
runtime: python3.8
layers:
  - {Ref: PythonRequirementsLambdaLayer}
package:
  individually: true

...

  pythonRequirements:
dockerizePip: non-linux
dockerImage: lambci/lambda:build-python3.8
layer: true
slim: true
slimPatterns:
  # the commented ones are included in slim: true
  # - '**/*.py[c|o]'
  # - '**/__pycache__*'
  # - '**/*.dist-info*'
  - '**/*.egg-info*'
  - '**/test/*'
  - '**/tests/*'
invalidateCaches: true
```